Azure App Service Load Balancing "SiteLoadBalancing.LeastRequests" is "Least Active Requests"?
The Azure App Service load balancing setting "SiteLoadBalancing.LeastRequests" is the "Least Active Requests" algorithm, right?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.powershell.cmdlets.websites.support.siteloadbalancing.leastrequests?view=az-ps-latest
SiteLoadBalancing.LeastRequests
Am I understanding that correctly?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/2121068/azure-app-service-load-balancing-siteloadbalancing
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/2121068/azure-app-service-load-balancing-siteloadbalancing

Yes, that's correct! The SiteLoadBalancing.LeastRequests setting in Azure App Service uses the "Least Active Requests" algorithm.

It directs traffic to the server with the fewest active requests at that moment, helping to evenly distribute the load across servers.

Thanks that does help a lot @SirraSneha :)


The Azure App Service load balancing setting "SiteLoadBalancing.LeastRequests" is the "Least Active Requests" algorithm, right?

Yes, you are correct. The Azure App Service load balancing setting SiteLoadBalancing.LeastRequests corresponds to the "Least Active Requests" algorithm.

It sends traffic to the server with the least number of active requests, helping to balance the load evenly across servers.
Please refer this doc for better understanding about load balancing.

To set the load balancing to SiteLoadBalancing.LeastRequests
Go to your Azure App Service - >Environment variables - > add below environment variable.

To test the load balancing behavior
Go to your azure app service - > click on scale out (app service plan) -> Increase the instance count to more than one

Use Application Insights to observe the load distribution across your instances.
You can also view metrics in your App Service, as following



The pictures are appreciated.

Yes, you are correct. The Azure App Service load balancing setting SiteLoadBalancing.LeastRequests uses the "Least Active Requests" algorithm. This means that incoming requests are directed to the instance with the least number of active requests at that moment.
